# Pycharm variable assignment not recognized inside try block

Tags: python, pycharm

```
try:
    driver = launch_browser()
except:
    print "Browser launch failed"

driver.get("http://www.example.com/")
```

The last line above is flagged by PyCharm with the following issue:

> Local variable "driver" might be referenced before assignment

However, something like this makes the error go away:

```
driver = None
try:
    driver = launch_browser()
except:
    print "Browser launch failed"

driver.get("http://www.example.com/")
```

Is there a way to setup PyCharm so that it will see the assignements inside try blocks?

Secondarily, can PyCharm figure out the type based on the return value of the function (in this case `launch_browser()`) if it has docstrings?

BTW, code works just fine in both cases. It's just a matter of getting PyCharm to understand the assignment inside the `try` block without having to resort to a band-aid.

**EDIT 1:**

A `return` in the `except:` block fixes the problem as far as PyCharm is concerned.  I was working on something else and inadvertently commented it out.  Proof that coding for 16 hours straight is a really bad idea...

Comment: You can tell PyCharm to ignore this kind of errors. But the question is why do you want to do such a thing?

Your current code can lead to unwanted behavior. Let's assume there'll be an exception during the browser launching, you *catch* the exception and print a message. Then you proceed with the program and try to apply `get` on the `driver`, which will lead to problems.

Comment: It says *"might be"*, which is accurate; you neither assign `driver` nor leave the function in the `except` block, so what's the point of it? Getting a `NameError` is much less helpful than seeing the error you just caught and discarded. Also bare `except:` is very bad practice.

Comment: Sorry, I over-simplified the example.  This isn't the actual code.  The real code does not continue execution after an exception and does not use a bare `except:`.

Comment: Local variable "driver" **is** referenced before assignment, every time when launch_browser() raises an exception. PyCharm is simply telling you the truth.

Comment: Concerning the secondary part: yes PyCharm has quite good type hinting/inspection capabilities. Check: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html

Comment: @martin's then could you provide an actually representative example?

Comment: Please see my edit.  Long day.  Making mistakes.  Should probably delete this question unless someone thinks it is of actual utility to anyone else...

Comment: @martin's speaking as a highly unimpartial (?) observer, I'd say keep the question and accept the awesome answer below. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: @RobertGrant  LOL.  Done.  It will probably be of use to someone as a warning not to work 16 hour days.  And, yes, good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `launch_browser()` fails, your code will error at the `driver.get("http://www.example.com/")` line. PyCharm is letting you know this.

The only way to avoid this is by not executing anything below the `except`, e.g. throwing an exception inside it, or putting everything that relies on `driver` inside an `else` block, which will only run if no exception is caught. E.g.

```
try:
    driver = launch_browser()
except:
    print "Browser launch failed"
else:
    driver.get("http://www.example.com/")
```

Comment: Rather than have further code in the `try` block, where errors you weren't planning for can be caught, move it to an `else` block.

Comment: Sorry yeah that's even smarter.